# boost_1_58_0 install fails on Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8

Tags: linux, rhel, compiling, boost

Get error during installation of boost:

```
#./b2

..failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.1.2/release/threading-multi/bzip2.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.1.2/release/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.1.2/release/threading-multi>bzip2.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/iostreams/build/gcc-4.1.2/release/threading-multi>libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.so for lack of <pstage/lib>libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
```

Comment: I am using Python 2.4.3

Comment: no output from # yum list | grep boost

Comment: Please do not use comments to add details that you left out; [edit] your question to make it better / clearer / more complete.

Comment: Could you please add some details to your question, ie is this Redhat Enterprise Linux and at least some versions. (GCC, GLIBC, Current Boost, Package Manager etc).  We cant find your problem with just a blob.  Also, what is the newest version of GCC and Python you can install from Yum?

Comment: It is Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8

Answer (score 1):

From the [Boost 1.58 Release Notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_58_0.html):

> ### Compilers Tested
>
> Boost's primary test compilers are:
>
> **Linux**:
>
> - Clang: 3.4
> - Clang, C++14: 3.5, 3.6
> - GCC: 4.4.7, 4.9.2
> - GCC, C++98: 4.8.1, 4.8.2
> - GCC, C++11: 4.4.7, 4.8.4, 4.9.2
> - GCC, C++14: 4.9.2
>
> **Windows**:
>
> - GCC, mingw: 4.4.7, 4.5.4, 4.6.3, 4.7.3, 4.8.2
> - Visual C++: 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0
>
> **FreeBSD**:
>
> - GCC: 4.2.1
>
> **QNX**:
>
> - QCC: 4.4.2
>
> Boost's additional test compilers include:
>
> **Linux**:
>
> - Clang: 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4
> - Clang, C++14: 3.5, 3.6
> - GCC: 4.4.7, 4.6.4, 4.7.3, 4.8.1, 4.9.2, 5.0.0 (experimental)
> - GCC, C++11: 4.4.7, 4.8.4, 4.9.2
> - GCC, C++14: 4.9.2
>
> **Windows**:
>
> - GCC, mingw: 4.4.7, 4.5.4, 4.6.4, 4.7.3
> - Visual C++: 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0
>
> **Android**:
>
> - Clang: 3.4, 3.5
> - GCC: 4.8, 4.9
>
> **FreeBSD**:
>
> - GCC: 4.2.1
>
> **QNX**:
>
> - QCC: 4.4.2

---

As you can see in the Primary Compiler List, there is no GCC 4.1.2.  As such the minimum requirement to upgrade to Boost 1.58 is GCC 4.4.7.  Using that same logic on the [older releases page](http://www.boost.org/users/history/),  4.1.2 is only listed as a minimum in Boost 1.53, meaning you need to upgrade GCC to at least 4.4.7, attempting to use your repositories then upgrade boost.  Please be aware that you must not upgrade GLIBC, or you may break your system.  You need a Side by Side Install of GCC.